# Versão do PHP sem phpinfo() ou phpversion()

Tags: php, versionamento, iis

Alguém sabe informar como verificar a versão do php sem utilizar o retorno de métodos?
Olhei o php.ini e lá também não tem muita coisa útil. O mais perto que cheguei foi a versão do php.exe e php-cgi.exe que é 5.2.7.7.

Posso confiar na informação dos executáveis ou essa não é a versão real que está instalada?

Publicação IIS(6 ¬¬)... Tem como saber por lá? Googlei mas não achei nada de útil...

Comment: `php -v` no terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por linha de comando:

```
php.exe --version
```

Mas cuidado: se você tiver mais de uma versão do php na máquina, o executável de linha de comando pode ser de uma, e o que roda no webserver, de outra.

Comment: **Muito obrigado!**
Fui até a pasta de instalação do php e executei o comando e fucionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Fiz o teste na minha maquina Win7-32 e ele gerou uma mensagem dizendo que o "CLI parou de funcionar" (isso acontece com qualquer parâmetro passado para o php.exe).


Mas após ver o que esse cara diz: 
http://web2.0entrepreneur.com/31/cli-has-stopped-working-on-windows-vista.html


 Ficou claro que o erro não era o sistema operacional ou uso do "XAMP".. O  problema é a versão do PHP... Apesar do "erro", o php não para de funcionar e o CLI(command line interface) também não.

Parece que na versão 5.2.0 e 5.2.3 esse erro não acontece.

Answer (score 1):

No meu computador existem duas versões do PHP, como sou desenvolvedor WEB eu testo as versões principalmente para visualizar a performance.

A versão que está configurada no meu IIS, eu verifico com `phpversion();` (que na pergunta você não quer) em um arquivo do PHP dessa forma:

```
<?php 
   phpversion();
```

Ou pelo plugin que eu instalo, que é PHP Manager (apesar que a versão correspondente para usá-lo é a IIS **7**<sup>**+**</sup>).

Por linha de comando, igual @bfavaretto já relatou, consigo verificar dentro da respectiva pasta qual versão é aquele PHP.

As duas maneiras são confiáveis e lhe dão o resultado esperado.